# Change timezone in android programmatically

Tags: android

I wanted to change timezone in android programmatically like to set timezone as "America/Los_Angeles". How can I do this. How can this be possible by using id's.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/>
```

In your source:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
```

Comment: I want to change the time zone locally for 3 different time zones.
1. EST(Eastern Standard Time). 
2. CST(Central Standard Time).
3. AST(Atlantic Standard Time).

From where I can select the key for the corresponding time zones?.

Comment: Call `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` to get the list of known timezones for your system.

Comment: This permission is only allowed for system apps.

Comment: on android api 26 and 27 receive this error: setTimeZone: Neither user 10087 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE.

Comment: change your code in AndroidManifest.xml to

  <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"
        android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem"></uses-permission>

Comment: I have the same @OmidZiyaee error. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 7):

Abhishek's code simply defines a Calendar instance with a specific format to be used in the app, so that will not work.

It is not possible to change the phone's timezone programmatically.
You could redirect the user to the appropriate settings, however:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: According to info from Synesso and HHLV, it is possible to set the time zone. Need to setup a permission and must be a system app. IDK how to setup as system app. Might not be possible for a regular (play store) app. But, I assume possible in some situations (i.e. embedded).

Answer (score 5):

If this is on a simulator or a device that you have root on, you could run

```
adb shell "su -c 'setprop persist.sys.timezone America/Los_Angeles; stop; sleep 5; start'"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();       
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813620/how-can-i-get-los-angeles-usa-current-time-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: That source is the answer to a different question and is not sufficient in this case.

Comment: Thanks. This answer somehow saved my life, because I kept set time zone on calendar instance only but not SimpleDateFormat, thats why I cannot get my shifted time anyway. I am at zone +8 for example, but I want my app display time from zone -7, this is what I want. Change it "programmatically". Voted up.

Answer (score -1):

You should have system signatures for setting timezones. if you are not manifacturer for your device may be you can contact them and ask for keystore files. after that you can sign your app as system with keystore file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30319186)