# How to set Australia Sydney Time Zone in My app programatically

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app that will be used in Australia.
I want to fix the timezone of device so that even if the user changes the timezone from Device setting, I will get Australia/Sydney Time Zone.
My app should not be dependent of Device set time zone.

I looked for answers but unsuccessful.
Whenever I am setting the Time Zone to Australia/Sydney it always returns the Current Location Time Zone.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Looks like this is generally the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/27540304/208273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of causes could be that you didn't allow your app to change time zone.
In your AndroidManifest.xml do you have this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/>
```

Another approach would be not to change time zone but change time format to extract time for different time zone:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();       
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));
String myTime=sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```